# How to maintain the emoji unicode which supports in web, andriod, ios?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, unicode

I have an application which is a messenger. In that I have emojis and now, I got a problem like I'm getting the emojis from the mobile and I'm converting that into unicode using the the below function.

```js
function emojiToUnicode(x) {
  return x.match(/\ud83c[\udf00-\udfff]|\ud83d[\udc00-\ude4f]|\ud83d[\ude80-\udeff]/g).map( e => "\\u" + e.charCodeAt(0).toString(16) + "\\u" + e.charCodeAt(1).toString(16) );
}
```

if i send :smile: im getting output as **\ud83d\ude0a** this string.

I'm getting the codes and it was fine for the browser. Now, If store this code in the database while rendering in android I'm getting the problem. How to convert the emoji to all device compatible format.

Comment: Why do you need to convert it? Emojis are part of unicode, can't you store it as any other text?

Comment: Because I'm using the google datastore for storing. If I send this emoji to datastore for storing it is storing as ??? marks. For this reason, I want to store emoji as a string. And it should be compatible with all devices like web and mobile.